# Rails 3 Check if Javascript is enable (serverside)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails-3

I found something on stackoverflow that works for prototype but I'm using jquery. Any ideas what I need to call instead?

[Check if Javascript is Enabled (Serverside) with Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2315648/check-if-javascript-is-enabled-serverside-with-rails)

```
function confirmJavascript()
{
    // Assuming you are using Prototype
    new Ajax.Request('/JavascriptController/confirm');
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to make an Ajax request to `'/JavascriptController/confirm'`, then you would do this:

```
$.ajax({
  url: '/JavascriptController/confirm'
  }
});
```

However, its never going to get sent if Javascript isn't enabled.

More info about making Ajax requests using jQuery is available here: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/