# Check whether javascript and cookies are enabled in ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to check whether javascript and cookies are enabled or not on page load in Ruby on Rails. So if anyone tries to open it, website should display a message that he cannot proceed further.

Comment: possible duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2315648/check-if-javascript-is-enabled-serverside-with-rails

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You coud use the `<noscript> ... </noscript>` tag. For more information look [here](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_noscript.asp).

Comment: Is there anyway to check it in application controller?

Comment: No not at all. As you have to load a page first.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to know this server side, you can set a cookie through javascript. If rails can't read it, than the user doesn't have cookies or javascript enabled.

Answer (score 0):

The `<noscript>` tag does not seem to work with script blockers like chrome ScriptSafe. For this case I have found a workaround: create an alert message that is removed, in case javascript works well.

This is the alert message with id="noscriptmessage":

```
<div id="noscriptmessage" style="color:red">
   This site requires javascript enabled!
</div>
```

And the following script will remove the message, if javascript is enabled and not blocked:

```
<script>
document.getElementById("noscriptmessage").innerHTML="";
</script>
```

Make sure that the script is found after the message (e.g., if you place the script in the header before the alert message, it will not work).

Comment: Sorry, I had missed the hint that this question was duplicate: see: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2315648/check-if-javascript-is-enabled-serverside-with-rails). There user "bobince" has described the same solution. You might want to check out that page, together with a ton of other possible solutions.