# Ruby on Rails check if javascript is enabled

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

How can I check in my layout code if the user has enabled javascript in his browser? 
If javascript is not enabled I want to show an error page. E.g. a 404 or a 500 error page. How can I do this with Rails?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13157135/check-whether-javascript-and-cookies-are-enabled-in-ruby-on-rails

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm not sure if checking for javascript within Rails is ideal. I found this if you really do want to do it: [Check if Javascript is Enabled (Serverside) with Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2315648/check-if-javascript-is-enabled-serverside-with-rails)

However, you can just show a message with `<noscript>` tag like:

```
<noscript>YOU DON'T HAVE JAVASCRIPT AND THAT OFFENDS ME</noscript>
```

Most browsers have javascript enabled by default so this is an uncommon problem. If you want you can include a `link_to` within the `<noscript>` in order to show them how to activate javascript like this:

```
<noscript>You don't have javascript enabled. Please follow this link for assistance in turning it on. <%= link_to "Turn on javascript", "http://www.enable-javascript.com" %>
```

**EDIT**

I just found this. I haven't tried it but it looks like exactly what you're looking for: [Ruby on Rails, Javascript detection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/745613/ruby-on-rails-javascript-detection)

```
<head>
    <!-- title, scripts, css etc go here -->
    <noscript>
        <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="2;url=http://yoursite.com/nojswarning.html">
    </noscript>
</head>
```